# How to make a Spinning animation in facebook/pop?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-pop

I have been searching for the whole internet about how to make a Spinning animation with facebook POP animation.

With no luck that kPOPLayerRotation only supports "Flip X/Y" animation, but not "Spin" (like the rotate property in front-end CSS), can anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#### Objective-C

```
POPSpringAnimation *rotateAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animation];
rotateAnimation.property = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName: kPOPLayerRotation];
rotateAnimation.toValue= @(M_PI/4);
```

#### Swift

```
let rotateAnimation = POPSpringAnimation(propertyName: kPOPLayerRotation)
rotateAnimation?.toValue = Double.pi / 4
```

Comment: Hi, lots of posts from the internet told me so, but I got this result, it is so weird. PS. I am using swift, and this is the code. https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4535844/26634426/38f724c4-4649-11e7-9a6d-8e89c7de10bb.png https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4535844/26634425/38f4d25a-4649-11e7-9443-0967ea38fc53.gif